# Optimize my algorithm for Detecting SQL Records that need to be updated

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a node app that is retrieving records from an API and `upserting` them to a MySQL DB.

The app will unconditionally pull all records from the last 6 months from the API (this will be run on a nightly basis). Let's say ~20k records will be downloaded every day.

Most of these 20k will probably be unaltered. Only a small amount may actually have changes in their rows.

Regardless, performing an `INSERT INTO ...ON DUPLICATE KEY..` will `UPSERT` all 20k rows in the DB (not just the altered records). I can confirm this by printing out the `result.affectedRows` in the callback and verifying it matches the count from the API. This isn't particularly a problem as it only takes a few seconds to upsert all rows.

However, after this, I want to retrieve all rows that had a `deleted` field get changed from `false` to `true`. So..let's say only 1 in 50 of the upserted rows actually had this get changed. I need to then somehow detect these 100 rows and then will `delete` them from another application (using this other app's REST-based API). So in a nutshell...this node app is a broker to synchronize records between 2 different apps.

Was thinking I could loop through all 20k..find their respective records in DB..and only `upsert` if there was a change? This is obviously inefficient and won't scale bc of the number of DB hits.
What kind of pattern can I use here to detect this? I'd rather not loop through every record.

Comment: What do you mean  by ' However, after this, I want to retrieve all rows that had a `deleted` field get changed from `false` to `true`. ' ? Can you please explain with example?

Comment: See my edit. thanks